# How to find defined integral $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x^{2}} \sin x d x $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x^{2}} \sin x d x
$$
I found out, that it can't be integrated via elementary functions properties. How should I dound it?

Comment: $f(-x)=-f(x)$,So $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $f(x)=e^{x^2}\sin x$ is an odd function ($f(-x)=-f(x)$), so $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx=0.$$

Comment: This better suits as a comment.

Comment: @Titi Eliatron Wow, thats truly amazing answer. So simple and elegant.